# Add Data in DataGridView According to the user's input

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, datagridview, sql-server-2014

I am a beginner in c#. I made a `DataGridView` in Visual Studio. I have `Item Code` ,  `Item Name` , `Cost Price` , `Sales Price` , `Quantity` and `Total` columns in my `DataGridView`. What I want is that when the user input the code in the `Item Code` I want to search that code in the Database and display the associated `Item Name` , `Cost Price` and  `Sales Price` automatically into the respective columns . Searching and fetching part I will do but how to know when the user has completed his input and then according to the input how to display the data accordingly. I don't have any idea how to Achieve that so I have not posted any code. if you think that you need the code to help, please specify which part of the code you want . thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can use "CellValueChanged" event of data grid view.

Comment: it may trigger every time the user change the value of any cell but I don't want that I want some event that occurs only when the user changes the value of `Item Code` column or cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
private void dtgProductDetail_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //For example:-
        //if(e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        if (e.ColumnIndex == "Put column index of Item Code.")
        {
            //Your function to bind values.
            //Searching of values in respect with Item Code from database.
            string ItemName="Value from db".
            string CostPrice="Value from db".
            string SalesPrice="Value from db".

            //Now put values in cells.
            //dtgProductDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Column Name"].Value = "Value to be inserted.";
            dtgProductDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Item Name"].Value = ItemName;
            dtgProductDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Cost Price"].Value = CostPrice;
            dtgProductDetail.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Sales Price"].Value = SalesPrice;
        }
    }
```

In case you have any query feel free to ask.

Comment: @Zaid, If you find it helpful then mark it answer so it will help others too.

Comment: it did help me for most part but how to add data to `Item Name` , `Cost Price` and `Sale price` specifically?

Comment: @Zaid, Updated answer as per your need please have a look over it.